# Channel network polyline shapefile filter

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, line, filter

I need to filter the red polyline shapefile keeping only the real channel network without the little features (noise). I use ArcGIS

[image]

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS but I can use also Qgis

Comment: Your data look pretty rough. Any chance you could re-classify the image and skeletonize it? If you want connected stream segments, you'd probably be better off tracing by hand rather than using the image you've posted as a starting point.

Comment: You traditionally extract a river network from a DEM, see [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/deriving-runoff-characteristics.htm) for an ArcGIS workflow. What ever you are doing seems to be pulling out roads and roundabouts?

Comment: Hornybydd thanks for your critic. I used WhiteboxGAT Map gully depth, because you can't apply some flow-based method as the one in your link for flat areas like that. And what I pulled out are not roads and roundabouts but the little streams near them.

Comment: Thank you John, I tried to use the "Thin" tool in ArcGIS to skeletonize the image but the results are that.. I was looking for something automatic

Comment: What image are you thinning? It should be binary--1 wherever you have river, else 0. It needs to be a single connected component if you want the skeleton to preserve the connectivity. If the image you're showing is a DEM, you could try thresholding it at some low elevation to get the binary channel mask.

Comment: The red colored polyline shapefile is produced using ArcScan form a raster processed with the thin tool

Comment: Yeah but you didn't answer the question: what image are you thinning? What is the "raster processed with the thin tool"?

Comment: I added the image up

Comment: You're still not being clear about what your original image(s) are. Are they RGB photos, a DEM, or what? What image did you "add up?"

Comment: It's a DEM, the one in background of the red polyline. Form that DEM I used the map gully depth to extract an image, that i reclassified in binary 0-1 (image up)

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question. Also, there is an [edit] button beneath your question which should be used to revise it with any requested clarifications.